# How to use Angular Material MatSort in a table that uses a template for header?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating a custom table control to be reusable across the project. I want this table to use `MatSort` internally. It also must be flexible so I use templates for header and body.

The problem is that I can't specify `mat-sort-header` on a `<th>` inside a template. In my project it just doesn't work (ignores the directive). I created a simplified stackblitz and there the console shows an error: `MatSortHeader must be placed within a parent element with the MatSort directive`.

[Here is the Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rkzyle)

I put there minimum amount of code to show the issue. What I want to achieve is something like this:

```html
<my-templated-table>
  <ng-template #header>
    <tr>
      <th mat-sort-header="sortable">Sortable</th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</my-templated-table>
```

Ideally even I'd like to have custom directive for sorting header so I can hide `MatSort` syntax from consumer.

I tried to find a solution for few hours now and whenever I find something similar enough it doesn't have answer. Also I've read that a directive cannot add another directive at runtime, so I don't know if my ideal approach is possible. Though I *feel* that both should be...

Answer (score 0):

on html template:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="items" matSort>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="columnName">
    <th id="1" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
         {{item.name}}
       </td>
 </ng-container>


  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

on ts file:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['columnName'];
```

Also you need add sort switch if required

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. Can I use this with a template? So when I use my table control I can pass the header as a template? It looks like the structure is fixed here and I can only pass an array of columns and the data.